# Using addShutdownHook in java

Tags: java

I want to do following operation in ordered wise

1. Stop jetty server

2. Delete used resource from jetty

3. Restart jetty server.

I have done this above using shutdownhook in java as below :

```
<code>

        Thread restartThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
                logger.debug("OS name:" + osName);
                if (osName != null
                        && osName.toUpperCase().startsWith("WINDOWS")) {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                List<String> cmdLine = new ArrayList<String>();
                                cmdLine.add("cmd.exe");
                                cmdLine.add("/C");
                                cmdLine.add("start");
                                cmdLine.add("\"\"");
                                cmdLine.add(getBaseDir() + File.separator + "restart.bat");

                                final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdLine);
                                Process process = pb.start();

                              if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
                                        // after stopping server delete stores
                                        deleteCertificates();

                                        // restores files
                                        restoreFiles(tmpdir, backupfilelist);
                                    } 

                                //p.waitFor();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                logger.error("Failed to restart:" + e.getMessage(), e);
                            } 
                        }
                    });
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service appservice restart");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error("Failed to restart:" + e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        restartThread.start();
<code>
```

my concern is will it do it sequentially execution, otherwise application will fail to restore.

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: Given the fact that the `Thread` is executing the process within a single `Thread` context then, yes, it should run in sequence...I'd be waiting for the `restart.bat` to complete before doing anything else

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ya my main concern is regarding restart service which might take some time, so i wanted to wait until that process is complete. So it should execute sequentially right?

Comment: I try to do same thing using concurrency CompletionService but it was throwing InterrruptedException after calling restart.bat